# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' for button tag

Tags: php

Hi tried editing code and i am trying to add an IF condition into the bit of php code /button. I got error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'" for button open tag line , what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 3171 ) ) {
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="addNewFAQS"><span class="plus-sign">+</span>
} ?>
    <?php esc_html_e('Add New', 'direo-extension'); ?>

</button>
```

Comment: You need to close PHP before using HTML, `?>` , or output with PHP, `echo 'HTML as a string';`.

Comment: @user3783243 ok thanks works now , i used: ```<?php
if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 3171 ) ) {
 Echo "<html>";
 Echo
      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="addNewFAQS"><span class="plus-sign">+</span>';

} ?>
    <?php esc_html_e('Add New', 'direo-extension'); ?>

</button>``` is that fine?

Comment: I'd remove the `Echo "<html>";` unless this is the start of a doc. A `button` as the first element seems like a strange design though. Syntactically that should be valid. Also `?>     <?php` is not needed. When you're in PHP you dont need to leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using below thanks to help from @user3783243

```
if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 3171 ) ) {
    Echo "<html>";
    Echo
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="addNewFAQS"><span class="plus-sign">+</span></button>';
 esc_html_e('Add New', 'direo-extension'); 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert HTML code into php for this you should echo it.

```
<?php
if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 3171 ) ) {
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="addNewFAQS"><span class="plus-sign">+</span>';
} ?>
```